# C - Invalid syntax allowed by compiler?

Tags: c, cmake, clion

When I learned C using Microsoft Visual Studio, it didn't allow me to create an array with a non-constant size. I had to either put a value like `int arr[5];` or do `#define size 5` and do `int arr[size];`. However today using Clion, I noticed it allows me to do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Enter a value: ");
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);

    int arr2[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        arr2[i] = i;
        printf("Array at %d is %d.\n", i, arr2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This C code compiles and runs without any problems -- no segment fault or anything. What's going on? Is this legal C code and I just learned in an IDE that didn't allow it, or is this invalid C code and I'm just using a bad compiler? On my other computer which is using Linux, I even installed GCC 7.2 and the same syntax is allowed. I don't understand. Is this a CLion issue, CMake issue, or a C lang issue?

My compiler and CMake are listed below. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: @chris While I appreciate a possible solution, can you explain some context to it? What it is, why should it be used, etc.

Comment: My bad, my brain was in C++ mode, where mistaken VLA usage is really common. The flag is for warning about using extensions.

Comment: You've overlooked one possibility: that the language has changed when you weren't looking!  Once upon a time, you're right, array sizes had to be constant, but in newer versions of the C Standard, supported by newer compilers, there are VLAs (Variable Length Arrays) where the size can be a variable.

Comment: If "18 years old" is counted as a "newer" standard! That's an eternity in computing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is valid C.  It is referred to as a **variable length array (VLA)**.  This feature was added to the language as part of the C99 standard.

MSVC is well known for not supporting many C99 and later features, including VLAs.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So then I have one final question: what environment should I code C in? Being able to code like this certainly takes a lot of burden off of having to make buffers of a certain size, guess and hope that it will be big enough for a user's input, etc. With VLA I don't have to worry about so much. Should I code in the C99 standard, Microsoft's weird C99 thing, or C11? Does the C programming community accept VLA or do hardcore C programmers think that it's against the way of the language. FYI I'm just a college student.

Comment: @Hatefiend If you're on a compiler that supports it and you don't need to worry about running in MSVC, go ahead and use it.  The alternative is to allocate memory dynamically using `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: Don't worry, I've been using `malloc` and `free` a ton for situations like this. I thought that was one of the main characteristics of the C language. With VLA, C suddenly reminds me a lot more of Java. That's why I'm asking what is the most popular C standard version for C programmers to use.

Comment: @Hatefiend If the evidence here on SO can be believed, everyone is using C99 or later.  Features like VLA's aren't new or different; they're just a regular part of the language now.  (Up above you can see someone teasing me -- and justifiably so -- for saying that they're part of "newer versions of the C Standard".)